# Multiple records per row

Tags: crystal-reports

My Details section currently looks like this:

[image]

How can I arrange it like this instead?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your Section Expert and select `Format with Multiple Columns.` This will make the `Layout` tab appear.

From that tab, you can set the relevant width such that four records appear per row. (Depending on the dimensions of the page.)